# RecyclerView Update Finish Callback

Tags: android

I have an `ArrayList<User>` that I constantly update with a background task and `RecyclerView.Adapter` that lists users' data. How can I know the Adapter finished updating Views so I can wait to update the user list. I want this because I don't want to update the user list while `RecyclerView` is updating to prevent half of the list to show old data and the other half the new data.

Answer (score 1):

I was updating the list from the background thread then call runOnUiThread to notify data changes. I realized that if I update the list from the main thread I don't have to worry about thread safety. Because even if another data update was detected in the middle of a `RecyclerView` update it will have to wait for the main thread to finish updating Views before updating the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

As of now google has not implemented such a feature because there was no need till now for such a thing.But when it comes i will surely update the answer with the link.

Answer (score 0):

Put this function inside your Callback function to show the result in the UI thread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do something
    }
});
```

ui elements don't wait for the response from the server, at the same time Callback is running not in UI thread. With this function, you can handle results and initiate some ui changes.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?